# How to calculate probability that something happens to n people out of N people in room?

Tags: probability, self-study

I don’t quite get how to solve this problem:

> There are 100 people in the room.  10 of them are suspected spies. We know for sure that 20 out of 100 people in the room are spies. What is the probability that not all 10 suspects in the room are spies (0 out of 10 are spies or 1 out of 10 are spies or 2 out of 10 are spies,..., or 9 out of 10 are spies)?

I don’t understand whether the events of suspected spies are interdependent.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a [tag:self-study] problem. I have added the tag. In future, kindly add the tag your self.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the accuracy of our suspicion. For example if when we suspect a person to be a spy we are correct 0% of the time, then the probability will be 0. If we are correct 100% of the time, then the probability would be 1.

But intuition tells me the question is asking about the probability of randomly guessing all 10 spies when the true number of spies in the sample of 100 is 20.

In this case we might rephrase this question and make it about balls and urns instead of people and spies. Then it would sound like this:

In the urn there are 100 balls. 20 of them are black and the rest are white. We draw 10 balls from the urn without replacement. What is the probability that all of those balls will be black?

See if you can pick it up and answer from this point.

Comment: i added some changes:  There are 100 people in the room. 10 of them are suspected spies. We know for sure that 20 out of 100 people in the room are spies. What is the probability that not all 10 suspects in the room are spies (0 out of 10 are spies or 1 out of 10 are spies or 2 out of 10 are spies,..., or 9 out of 10 are spies)

Comment: and why we draw 10 balls from the urn without replacement?

Comment: Hello @manabou11 , you should not add changes to questions posted by other users. But regardless - your addition is just the inverse of the original. For example, if the probability of guessing all 10 correctly is 0.1, then the probability of guessing at least one incorrectly is 0.9. This is a well known "trick" for these kinds of calculations. So first get the probability of the unedited questions. Then subtract the answer from 1.

Comment: Without replacement, because once you guess a person to be a spy, you cannot guess him to be a spy a second time - he is already a suspect. Doing this with replacement would assume that you can guess the same person to be a spy 2 or more times.

Comment: so the answer is: 1 - 20/100 + 19/99 + 18/98 + 17/97 + 16/96 +…+ 11/91 ?

Comment: Not quite. The probability of drawing 1 black ball from the urn with 20 black balls out of 100 is 20/100. So this part is correct. Now as a next step think about drawing out 2 black balls. For some sanity check - the probability of drawing 2 black balls should be lower than the probability of drawing just 1 black ball. It's a rarer event - harder to achieve. If we calculate it the way you did it we would get that the probability to draw 2 is higher than drawing just 1.

Comment: My problem is that the question seems to be hinting at two strong but dubious assumptions: the suspicion has no skill (a spy and a non-spy are equally likely to be suspected) and may be independent of other suspicions

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius why we drawing out 2 black balls in second step?

Comment: @manabou11 just as a demonstration. Since you are learning about these things, so I suggest doing it step by step. Before calculating the answer for 10 - do it for 2 instead. Also are you the same person as "Ir8_mind" ? In this case you should use that account and edit the original question. These comments are becoming a bit too long.

Comment: @Henry yeah I agree 100%, seems like a weird context for a question like this because the first thing that comes to mind is that usually suspicions should not be baseless.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius so what would a solution? i still don't get it

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius because we know who are suspended spies, i think that probability is (0.2)^10. is it correct?

Comment: @manabou11 short answer: when you are calculating a probability of multiple events occurring one after the other you should multiply the probabilities, not add them up like in your proposed answer.